# Emacs display only 12 list elements

Tags: list, printing, emacs, pretty-print

I've tried to print the state of the list by message function

```
(message "%s" '(aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu oeu oeu aoe))
```

But unfortunately see only 12 elements and 3 dots in the end.

```
"(aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu aoeu oeu oeu ...)"
```

Any suggestions here how to inspect whole state of any list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See variables [`print-length`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Variables.html) and, especially, [`eval-expression-print-length`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html).